# Jquery On change array ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have multiple selector on loop in php code

```js
var new_acc =  $("div[id^=new_acc]").hide();
for (var i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
 $('#reason_change\\['+id+'\\]').change(function(e) {
  
    $( "#reason_change\\["+id+"\\] ").show();
 
 });

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="reason_change[1]" id="reason_change[1]" >
 <option value="0">--0000--</option>
 <option value="1">--0001--</option>
 <option value="2">--0002--</option>             
</select>

<div class="field" id="new_acc[1]">
 <label>Account</label>
 <input type="text" name="account_cus[1]"  id="account_cus[1]" value="">
</div>

<select name="reason_change[2]" id="reason_change[2]" >
 <option value="0">--0000--</option>
 <option value="1">--0001--</option>
 <option value="2">--0002--</option>
</select>
<div class="field" id="new_acc[2]">
 <label>Account</label>
 <input type="text" name="account_cus[1]"  id="account_cus[2]" value="">
</div>
```

if i click on change my selctor id = reason_change[2] i wanna show  id="new_acc[2]" showing

Comment: The variable `i` doesn't seem to be used within the loop, is that what you meant?

Comment: what is id? it never changes.... also it makes zero sense to loop over like that with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS doesn't need the loop and doesn't need to reference the individual element IDs, because you can select all of the select elements at once and bind a single change handler to them, then within the handler use `this` to reference the changing element and (DOM navigation method) [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) to get its associated div element:

```
$("select[id^=reason_change]").change(function() {
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

If you wanted to make it so that the div is only shown when certain values are selected in the select element, and hidden otherwise, you can do something like this:

```js
var new_acc =  $("div[id^=new_acc]").hide();
$("select[id^=reason_change]").change(function() {
  if(this.value === "2") {  // show only if certain option is selected
    $(this).next().show();
  } else {
    $(this).next().hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="reason_change[1]" id="reason_change[1]" >
 <option value="0">--0000--</option>
 <option value="1">--0001--</option>
 <option value="2">--0002--</option>             
</select>

<div class="field" id="new_acc[1]">
 <label>Account</label>
 <input type="text" name="account_cus[1]"  id="account_cus[1]" value="">
</div>

<select name="reason_change[2]" id="reason_change[2]" >
 <option value="0">--0000--</option>
 <option value="1">--0001--</option>
 <option value="2">--0002--</option>
</select>
<div class="field" id="new_acc[2]">
 <label>Account</label>
 <input type="text" name="account_cus[1]"  id="account_cus[2]" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: if i wanna choose reason_change[2] = 4 then  id="new_acc[2]" will be show how can i do thx guys.

Comment: In your sample HTML you don't have any options with value of "4", but I've updated my answer to only show the div when the selected value is "2" - you should be able to extrapolate from there to apply more complicated conditions if needed...

Comment: sorry i forgot to add <option value="4">--0004--</option> on my code

Comment: No problem. You should be able to see in my existing answer how to use that option.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var new_acc =  $("div[id^=new_acc]").hide();
$("select[id^=reason_change]").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() === "2"){
    $(this).next().show();
  } else {
   $(this).next().hide();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="reason_change[1]" id="reason_change[1]" >
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
 <option value="0">--0000--</option>
 <option value="1">--0001--</option>
 <option value="2">--0002--</option>             
</select>

<div class="field" id="new_acc[1]">
 <label>Account</label>
 <input type="text" name="account_cus[1]"  id="account_cus[1]" value="">
</div>

<select name="reason_change[2]" id="reason_change[2]">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
 <option value="0">--0000--</option>
 <option value="1">--0001--</option>
 <option value="2">--0002--</option>
</select>
<div class="field" id="new_acc[2]">
 <label>Account</label>
 <input type="text" name="account_cus[1]"  id="account_cus[2]" value="">
</div>
```